# publish 5 words from model title django

Tags: python, django

I have a model :

```
  class publish(models.Model):
    publish_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Publish_Your_Story=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.Publish_Your_Story)
```

I have views.py :

```
class Index(ListView):
    model=publish
```

Template:

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
 <ul>
{% for article in object_list %}
<li>{{ article }}</li>
 {% empty %}
   <li>No articles yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Now i want to publish only 10 words from Publish_Your_Story row from models as article in Template . Kindly help .

Comment: [`truncatewords`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords)

Comment: Let me try once .

Comment: Thanks mate . put your ans as Ans . i will up vote you

Comment: @DanielRoseman Make it an answer, as it is the correct answer to the question.